# How to store multiple textbox values of different classification into one table?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Please refer this picture :
[image: FormUI]

So, I've made a form consisting 11x3 textboxes for 11 machines. One machine has 3 textboxes of parameters.

My table is named TOSA_settings and the fields are as below:
UCL
LCL
mean
machine

I've disabled all textboxes because user shall be able to edit/update any machine that they ONLY want to update. If user want to update machine 1, he will click on edit label at the right side of TOSA 01 textboxes and the textboxes will be enabled=true. User can fill in data then save only for that particular machine. Where the rest will remain disabled.

Now, i only try coding for two machine to see if it works.

Thus, I wrote the code as this under cmdSave_Click()

```
Dim strSQL As String

If mean1.Value <> "" Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TOSA_settings( UCL, LCL, mean, machine) VALUES (" & Me.UCL1 & "," & Me.LCL1 & ", " & Me.mean1 & ", 'TOSA 01');"
End If
If mean2.Value <> "" Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TOSA_settings( UCL, LCL, mean, machine) VALUES (" & Me.UCL2 & "," & Me.LCL2 & ", " & Me.mean2 & ", 'TOSA 02');"
End If
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnEror
```

But it only save the values from TOSA 02. 
or should I create other tables, one machine each?

Comment: Instead of action SQL in VBA, should use a form in Continuous view bound to table and have only 1 set of textboxes for data entry. Each new set of data would be entered into new record row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to execute twice (or multiple):

```
Dim strSQL As String

If mean1.Value <> "" Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TOSA_settings( UCL, LCL, mean, machine) VALUES (" & Me.UCL1 & "," & Me.LCL1 & ", " & Me.mean1 & ", 'TOSA 01');"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnEror
End If
If mean2.Value <> "" Then
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TOSA_settings( UCL, LCL, mean, machine) VALUES (" & Me.UCL2 & "," & Me.LCL2 & ", " & Me.mean2 & ", 'TOSA 02');"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnEror
End If
```